# Specify custom parameters in WSP deploy / feature activation?

Tags: 2010, feature-activation, solution-deployment, term-store

I have a Feature Receiver where I access the Term Store to get / set something.

My problem is, the code needs to connect to 'specific' term store.. but what if the Term store name changes when I deploy to different environments?

Is there a way where before activation of the feature I can "request" for a parameter (ex. Term Store name) to which I can use in the Feature Receiver?

Thank you!

Edit: I am using SharePoint 2010.

Comment: What is the scope of the feature?

Comment: Hello, the scope is for the Site Collection.

Comment: You can put the specific term store name in the Site property bag and in the feature receiver fetch it from there

Comment: Wow, that looks interesting! I'll give it a go and get back to you :D Thanks!

Comment: Hey, it worked great! Thanks very much! How can I mark you as anwer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put the specific term store name in the Site property bag and in the feature receiver fetch it from there.